# Parse SDK causes an entitlements resource error when building for AppStore

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, parse-platform

It looks like XCode6 is not signing the resources within the Parse SDK (of which I'm using the latest version, 1.4.1).

The actual Archive/Build works fine. In fact I'm also able to distribute AdHoc beta builds through this process just fine (and my testers are able to install from HockeyApp). The problems don't happen until I try to submit to the AppStore. I switch over to the Distribution profile & certificate, archive, and then when I press the Submit button from the Organizer I get this:

[image]

When I click on Show Logs, I'm taken to the finder path `/private/var/folders/s_/9v750_vs1ql7ftn5zq8cn9y80000gn/T/`. The folder contains 3 files, two of which have nothing new, but one of which (`IDEDistribution.standard.log`) contains an interesting error pointing at Parse:

```
2014-09-24 04:34:05 +0000 [MT] Beginning distribution assistant for archive: Aftermath-iOS[APPSTORE], task: Submit
2014-09-24 04:34:05 +0000 [MT] Automatically selecting the only availaable distribution method <IDEDistributionMethodiOSAppStoreDistribution: 0x7fb300688930>
2014-09-24 04:34:06 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for <DVTFilePath:0x7fb2edd3f190:'/Users/zane/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2014-09-23/Aftermath-iOS[APPSTORE] 9-23-14, 9.34 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Aftermath.app/Parse.framework/Versions/A'>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/zane/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2014-09-23/Aftermath-iOS[APPSTORE] 9-23-14, 9.34 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Aftermath.app/Parse.framework/Versions/A" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo=0x7fb2ede17c40 {NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/zane/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2014-09-23/Aftermath-iOS[APPSTORE] 9-23-14, 9.34 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Aftermath.app/Parse.framework/Versions/A" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2014-09-24 04:34:09 +0000 [MT] Canceled distribution assistant
```

Note the line about `archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent` being missing from the build target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being a silly mistake on my part. I had the Parse Framework in the copy resources phase, which is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Could be because you might have copied your third party libraries into embed libraries section.Removing them can resolve this issue.