# Trouble With Parse When Submitting to App Store

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

```
2015-05-26 14:37:31 +0000 [MT] Beginning distribution assistant for archive: TrophyMania, task: Submit
2015-05-26 14:37:31 +0000 [MT] Automatically selecting the only availaable distribution method <IDEDistributionMethodiOSAppStoreDistribution: 0x7f9d04c3c8f0>
2015-05-26 14:37:31 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for <DVTFilePath:0x7f9d06b5a4d0:'/Users/[Username]/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-05-26/TrophyMania 2015-05-26, 10.37 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TrophyMania.app/parse-library-1.7.2/ParseFacebookUtils.framework'>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/[Username]/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-05-26/TrophyMania 2015-05-26, 10.37 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TrophyMania.app/parse-library-1.7.2/ParseFacebookUtils.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo=0x7f9d04d46710 {NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/[Username]/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-05-26/TrophyMania 2015-05-26, 10.37 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TrophyMania.app/parse-library-1.7.2/ParseFacebookUtils.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2015-05-26 14:37:36 +0000 [MT] Canceled distribution assistant
```

Hello, after archiving my app, I can choose to 'validate' it or 'Submit to the App Store'. Pressing either of these yields an error that is stored in the above log.

Can anyone help me with this? It is very concerning. I used the instructions provided by https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/swift/existing & the project executes and builds fine. I've already accomplished much of what I wanted to do with the Parse frameworks within the project.

I am running `iOS 8.3` .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26022919/1702413

Comment: For anyone who reads this, the link offered by @TonyMkenu solved the issue : ) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Havent faced such issue while uploading the application but i have alternative if you would like to try.

- Build your project
- Zip your .app file
- Upload it using application loader

Comment: Do you recommend I try zipping it using the export option after archiving? Or can I use any zip application to do that? I will give it a try- a link to any instructions would help.

Comment: Build you app using Command+B.. Open you .app in finder. Zip it & upload it using Application loader..

Comment: `ERROR ITMS-90174: "Missing Provisioning Profile - iOS Apps must contain a provisioning profile in a file named embedded.mobileprovision."`

Comment: Have you set provisional profile setup properly in Build Settings of target?

Comment: It is automatic provisioning.